# Get value of combobox2 from combobox1

Tags: c#, visual-studio, combobox

I got 2 comboboxes on my form(in the form load event). First combobox gets a value from a select statement once the form loads. I want to use that value in my second combobox. Here is my code:

**1ste Combobox = cbDelivery**

```
        OracleConnection conn = new OracleConnection();
        conn.ConnectionString = "User Id=christob;Password=CHRISTOB;Host=poseidon;Pooling=true;Min Pool    Size=0;Max Pool Size=100;Connection Lifetime=0;Port=1522;Sid=GLODCD";

        conn.Open();

        string query;
        query = "select distinct dd.delivery_bay_code from dc_delivery dd, dc_grv dg where delivery_complete_datetime is null and dd.dc_delivery_id_no = dg.dc_delivery_id_no and dd.delivery_announce_datetime is null";
        OracleCommand cmd = new OracleCommand(query, conn);
        OracleDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        while (dr.Read())
        {
            cbDelivery.Items.Add(dr["delivery_bay_code"]);
        }
        dr.Close();
        conn.Close();
```

**2de Combobox = cbOrderNo**

This combobox is in:

> private void cbDelivery_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs
>   e)

so as soon as I select a value from 1ste combobox my 2nd combobox query must populate the 2nd combobox. See code:

```
        OracleConnection conn = new OracleConnection();
        conn.ConnectionString = "User Id=christob;Password=CHRISTOB;Host=poseidon;Pooling=true;Min Pool Size=0;Max Pool Size=100;Connection Lifetime=0;Port=1522;Sid=GLODCD";
        conn.Open();
        string query1;
        query1 = "select distinct dg.order_no from dc_delivery dd, dc_grv dg where delivery_complete_datetime is null and dd.dc_delivery_id_no = dg.dc_delivery_id_no and dd.delivery_announce_datetime is null and dd.delivery_bay_code = " + cbDelivery.Text;
        OracleCommand cmd1 = new OracleCommand(query1, conn);
        OracleDataReader dr1 = cmd1.ExecuteReader();
        while (dr1.Read())
        {
            cbOderNo.Items.Add(dr1["order_no"]);

        }
        dr1.Close();
        conn.Close();
```

Note I'm using cbDelivery combobox in my second Select query.

Problem is:
As soon as I select a value from my first combobox the second gives an exception ""ORA-00904: "BAY1": Invalid Identifier.

Please help me sort this out or suggest a different method.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Did you try cbDelivery.SelectedValue instead of cbDelivery.Text. Also you are missing single quotes around your sql query. So this line: query1 = "select distinct dg.order_no from dc_delivery dd, dc_grv dg where delivery_complete_datetime is null and dd.dc_delivery_id_no = dg.dc_delivery_id_no and dd.delivery_announce_datetime is null and dd.delivery_bay_code = '" + cbDelivery.Text + "'";

Comment: @AzharKhorasany cbDelivery.SelectedValue doesn't do it.  Also "'" doesn't work. Don't think there is something wrong with the query. It works like that in my other one's.

Comment: Put a breakpoint on your query variable and see what string you get when you execute it. Then run that query in Oracle database to see whether you can get any results?

Comment: @AzharKhorasany Yes, that query works in Oracle. Im getting a exception at OracleDataReader dr1 = cmd1.ExecuteReader(); -- ""ORA-00904: "BAY1": Invalid Identifier.

Comment: Have a look at this. There must be something wrong in your query: http://www.dba-oracle.com/t_ora_00904_string_invalid_identifier.htm

Comment: Ok. Here is a tip. One of the words in your query is a reserved word in Oracle. Change that word and it should run. Also this column "delivery_complete_datetime" belongs to which table? dg or dd?

Comment: @AzharKhorasany I have changed every word/Alias i could change..Still nothing. And 'delivery_complete_datetime' is in the dd table. Changed that as well. Im getting so frustrated /:

Comment: @AzharKhorasany thanks for the help. I solved the issue. Please see code below if you are interested.
BTW, your first comment actually did help at the end.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

FIXED!! This is how i did it:

```
private void populateDeliveryBayCodes()
    {
        conn.Open();
        string query;
        query = "select distinct dd.delivery_bay_code from dc_delivery dd, dc_grv dg where dd.delivery_complete_datetime is null and dd.dc_delivery_id_no = dg.dc_delivery_id_no and dd.delivery_announce_datetime is null";
        OracleCommand cmd = new OracleCommand(query, conn);
        OracleDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        while (dr.Read())
        {
            cbDelivery.Items.Add(dr["delivery_bay_code"]);
        }
        dr.Close();
        conn.Close();
    }

    private void populateOrderNumbers()
    {
        conn.Open();
        string query;
        query = "select distinct dg.order_no from dc_delivery dd, dc_grv dg where dd.delivery_complete_datetime is null and dd.dc_delivery_id_no = dg.dc_delivery_id_no and dd.delivery_announce_datetime is null and dd.delivery_bay_code ='" + cbDelivery.Text + "' order by order_no";
        OracleCommand cmd = new OracleCommand(query, conn);
        OracleDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        while (dr.Read())
        {
            cbOderNo.Items.Add(dr["order_no"]);
        }
        dr.Close();
        conn.Close();
    }
```

and

```
private void frmBuiltPallet_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        populateDeliveryBayCodes();
    {

private void cbDelivery_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        populateOrderNumbers();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

May be your query using some keyword of sql or oracle as column name or at some invalid place. in such cases this type of errors are possible. I am not sure about this solution. but atleast we can try once. so that we can make it sure if its correct or not?